# Magento language switcher how to show unselected language

Tags: magento

Please I need your help to show unselected language instead of the selected.

in other words, if you open default language (English) will load and in the top bar will show English to click on it to change to French so i need to show French if the store using English view and same if using French view will show English in topbar.

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language top-select">
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" style="width:auto;">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>" <?php if($lang_flag): ?> data-image="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/'.$_lang->getCode().'.png'); ?>" <?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $("#select-language").selectbox();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```